# run java project in ant

Tags: java, ant, swt

Im trying to run my java project  (two programs, server and client) in ant. This is my build.xml

```
<project name="myproject" default="run" basedir=".">
<description>Client Server gui project</description>

<property name="srcdirserver" location="src/src_server"/>
<property name="srcdirclient" location="src/src_client"/>
<property name="lib" location="lib"/>
<property name="build" location="build"/>
<property name="buildserver" location="build/server"/>
<property name="buildclient" location="build/client"/>
<property name="dest_server" location="dest-server"/>
<property name="dest_client" location= "dest-client"/>
<property name="examples" location="examples"/>
<property name="doc" location="doc"/>




   <!-- CLEAN -->
   <target name="clean">
      <delete dir="${build}"/>
      <delete dir="${dest_server}"/>
     <delete dir="${dest_client}"/>
   </target>

   <!-- COMPILE (Dummy)-->
   <target name="compile" depends="clean,compileserver,compileclient,jarserver,jarclient,documentation">
   </target>

   <!-- DOCUMENTATION -->
   <target name="documentation">
   <javadoc sourcepath="${srcdirserver}" destdir="${doc}" encoding="UTF-8" charset="UTF-8"></javadoc>
   </target>

   <!-- COMPILE (Server code)-->
   <target name="compileserver" depends="clean">
      <mkdir dir="${buildserver}"/>
      <javac includeantruntime="false"
             srcdir="${srcdirserver}"
             destdir="${buildserver}" 
             encoding="UTF-8"
             classpath="${src}"/>
   </target>
   <!-- COMPILE (Client code)-->
   <target name="compileclient" depends="clean">
      <mkdir dir="${buildclient}"/>
      <javac includeantruntime="false"
             srcdir="${srcdirclient}"
             destdir="${buildclient}" 
             encoding="UTF-8"
             classpath="${lib}/swt.jar:${src}"/>
   </target> 
   <!-- BUILD JAR (server) -->
    <target name="jarserver" depends="clean,compileserver">
    <mkdir dir="${dest_server}"/>
    <jar destfile="${dest_server}/myserver.jar" 
         basedir="${buildserver}">
    <manifest>
    <attribute name="Main-Class"
    value="game_server.main.Init"/>
    </manifest>
    </jar>
    <mkdir dir="${dest_server}/examples"/>
    <copy todir="${dest_server}/examples" >  
        <fileset dir="${examples}" includes="**"/>  
    </copy>
    </target>

    <!-- BUILD JAR (client) -->
    <target name="jarclient" depends="clean,compileclient">
    <mkdir dir="${dest_client}"/>
    <jar destfile="${dest_client}/myclient.jar" 
         basedir="${buildclient}">
    <manifest>
    <attribute name="Main-Class"
    value="game_client.main.Gui"/>
    <attribute name="Class-Path"
    value="lib/swt.jar"/>
    </manifest>
    </jar>
    <mkdir dir="${dest_client}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${dest_client}/lib"/>
    <copy file="${lib}/swt.jar"
    todir="${dest_client}/lib"/>
    </target>

   <!-- RUN -->
    <target name="run" depends="compile,jarserver,jarclient">
       <parallel>
           <java jar="${dest_server}/myserver.jar" dir="${dest_server}" fork="true"/>
           <java jar="${dest_client}/myclient.jar" dir="${dest_client}" fork="true"/>
       </parallel>
    </target>
</project>
```

Server works fine, but client with gui is compiled/archived into jar  successfuly, but when i run it it throws this error:
/EDIT: i found out i was using wrong swt.jar version i downloaded proper now, but still getting similar error :/

```
run:
     [java] OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /home/blackened/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gtk-4332.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
     [java] It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
     [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
     [java]     no swt-gtk-4332 in java.library.path
     [java]     no swt-gtk in java.library.path
     [java]     Can't load library: /home/blackened/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gtk-4332.so
     [java]     Can't load library: /home/blackened/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gtk.so
     [java]     /home/blackened/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gtk-4332.so: /home/blackened/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gtk-4332.so: Kódovanie dát v ELF súbore nie je little-endian (Possible cause: endianness mismatch)
     [java] 
     [java]     at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at game_client.main.Gui.open(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at game_client.main.Gui.main(Unknown Source)
     [java] Java Result: 1
```

Im using Fedora 18 (Spherical Cow) OS. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like SWT is looking for the 32-bit version of those 2 jars, but all you have installed is the 64-bit version, judging from the **x86_64** in the path.

Also, you say you're on Fedora, but it's trying to load what appear to be Windows-related jars.

The 'unsatisifed link' error is likely coming from it trying to find DLLs that aren't there, instead of the .so files it should be looking for on Linux.

This may help:
http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#missingdll

Comment: i found out that /usr/lib/jni folder is missing in my PC, what should i install? I found tons of tutorial for ubuntu but nothing for fedora :(

Comment: I'm an Ubuntu guy myself, but it appears that, from this doc, that 64-bit JNI is supposed to ship with Fedora by default: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Core/6/html/Release_Notes/ar01s13s02.html. So it may be that your Java install is messed up.

Comment: One thing that's possible perhaps is that you need the client side of the JNI libraries. For example, on Ubuntu, there is a package called `libswt-gtk-3-jni`, which is listed as `Standard Widget Toolkit for GTK+ JNI library`. It's possible you may need a package like that. There's a yum package called `libswt3-gtk2.x86_64` that I can see that may also come into play, depending on what version of GTK you're using. You may need either that package or (what I assume exists) `libswt3-gtk3.x86_64`.

Comment: yeah but thats probably for CentOS. (No package libswt3-gtk2.x86_64 available. / No package libswt3-gtk3.x86_64 available. ) / edit: so I tried uninstall gtk, and broken my fedora (gone dark in centre of uninstalling :[)

Comment: You could perhaps try reinstalling it from a tty. There aren't any similarly named packages for `libswt` that contain `jni`?